# How to change the code so that it is in 1 line

Tags: kotlin

This code searches for characters in a string that occur in at least **two** words.

**For example**:

**input**: hello world

**output**: lo

I don’t know how you can transform this code so that it is written in one line, is it even possible?
I am just starting to learn the Kotlin programming language, so I ask for help

```
    fun main() {
    
    var s = readLine();
    var w = Array(128){0}
    var g = Array(128){0}
    if(s!=null)
    {
        for(c in s)
        {
            if(c.toInt() != 32)
            {
                w[c.toInt()] = 1
            }
            for(k in 0..127)
            {
                if(w[k] == 1)
                {
                    g[k] += 1
                    w[k] = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    //for last word
    for(k in 0..127)
    if (w[k] == 1)
    {
        g[k] += 1
        w[k] = 0
    }
    
    
    //PRINT
    for(k in 0..127)
    {
        if(g[k] > 1) print(k.toChar())
    }
   }
```

Comment: There may be better ways to program this yes, but what is the point of changing it to a one-line code? It will not make your program faster nor more readable.

Comment: @Andrew This algorithm, the fastest and possibly more readable than the code will be written in one line, I just wanted to shorten it to one line.

Comment: Nah, I think that is impossible. As said before, there are ways to program the above written code better, but not in one line. I advise you to dive deeper in kotlin programming.

Comment: @Andrew Using helper functions filter, map, reduce - Is this not possible to do?
Except for input and output.

Comment: what does this code do? and use meaningful variable names

Comment: @IR42 
This code searches for characters that occur in at least two words.
Example.
INPUT: hello world
output: lo

Comment: Readability and possibly performance are good goals for your code. Making it concise at the expense of clarity is not good practice unless you're playing code golf.

Comment: @Tenfour04 
I play teacher golf

Comment: I'm not sure what teacher golf is, or what your goal actually is. For instance, this looks deliberately hard to read: `c.toInt() != 32`

Comment: Why? 
this code, only chek on backspace

Comment: @Tenfour04 
the first task was to do the fastest possible in speed, the second with the maximum expressiveness of the code

Comment: Except for special cases such as code golf, conciseness is only one of many goals; readability, maintainability, clarity, robustness, and simplicity are all arguably more important.  On the other hand, where all else is equal, shorter code _is_ simpler and clearer, so it's not a bad goal to have, as long as you balance it with the others.  In this particular case, the one-character variables and inconsistent spacing already make it hard to read…  And from all the type conversions, I'm guessing it was converted automatically from Java?

Comment: @gidds No this code is converted from python

Comment: So is this a third task to do it with conciseness? Extreme conciseness is definitely less expressive. Anyway, here is a one-line abomination: `readLine()?.run { split(' ').map(CharSequence::toSet).flatten().fold(mutableMapOf<Char, Int>()) { map, c -> map.also { map[c] = map.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1 } }.filterValues { it >= 2 }.keys.joinToString("").let { println(it) } }`

Comment: @Tenfour04 I forgot to tell in work to use a mutable collection and var variables.

Comment: @Tenfour04 You could shave a few chars off that by using `.map{ it.toSet() }` in place of `map(CharSequence::toSet)`.  And probably by removing many of the spaces.  You might even be able to remove the `let` by putting the whole expression in the `println()`.  It is already, as you say, an unreadable mess, so making it even worse isn't an issue at this point…

Comment: @Gidds Yeah, I still don't really know what the goal is. Maybe it is code golf? But now there's some new requirement that `var`s be used? I didn't notice there's already an answer now and it's more concise.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thx for your answer on my question!

Comment: @Tenfour04 can you help me with one more answer?

Comment: Sure, just post another question on this site.

Comment: Okey, need wait 90 minutes(

Comment: @Tenfour04 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64011457

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun main() {
    val input = readLine() ?: return

    val result = input.split(" ")
        .flatMap { it.toSet() }
        .groupBy { it }
        .filterValues { it.size > 1 }
        .keys
        .joinToString(separator = "")

    println(result)
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with one more question on Kotlin programming?

Comment: @roxyashechka https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: Okey, need wait 90 minutes(

Comment: Excellent answer! That code is _far_ easier to read and understand than the question! (It's also shorter, but that's more of a useful side-effect than a goal in itself.)