# How to modify the code so that the selection condition can be passed as an argument

Tags: kotlin

I have a code like this, needs to be modified in such a way that -
the selection condition could be passed as an argument (one of the function arguments must be lambda with a value by default - the condition that was specified in your option).

This program calculates the sum of digits in multiples of 3

**Example**:

- INPUT : 123456789
- OUTPUT: 18 (3+6+9 = 18)

**Code:**

```
fun main() {
  val s = readLine();
  println(s?.map(Character::getNumericValue)?.filter{ it.toInt() % 3 == 0 }?.sum());
}
```

Comment: So your ]program treats each character as an integer, and returns the sum of the ones that match a selection condition? But you want to be able to type some selection condition into the console? Need more explanation to understand. If you need to accept input of the selection condition from the console, you need to define a syntax for it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 No, the selection condition does not need to be entered into the console, just so that you can change it in the code
instead of multiples of 3 possible multiples of 2

Comment: If you’re asking how to write a function with arguments, that is so fundamental I think you just need to read the basics of Kotlin before asking questions here. It’s a waste of people’s time to try to explain something so fundamental if you haven’t even done any research about it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I think this is not the basic syntax, because I have revised the documentation a lot, but nothing worked, only for this reason with such a request on the stack

Comment: Can you show what you tried so we can see what you’re stuck on?

Comment: What's the problem you're encountering? You can extract the code in a function like `fun String.getSumDivisibleBy(n: Int) = this.map(Character::getNumericValue).filter { it.toInt() % n == 0 }.sum()`, then call it with whatever number: `println(yourString.getSumDivisibleBy(3))`. You can use `?.let` block to do null checks, try yourself to understand better. Practical knowledge is more important than asking and copy pasting the answer.

Comment: @ Animesh Sahu
Thank you very much, maybe you can help with a couple more questions?
I will try to create the function myself

Comment: @ Animesh Sahu
It is necessary that the lambda argument is passed to the function example
nameFunction (Default argument, lambda argument that can condition the algorithm)